# How can I get my Logitech Dual Action gamepad to work with DuckTales Remastered?

Tags: steam, pc, controllers, ducktales-remastered

My Logitech Dual Action gamepad is detected by Steam and the Logitech setup utility, but it does not work at all with DuckTales Remastered.  Others are having the same issues with the same gamepad as well as others.

The working solution is to use an Xbox controller or download pay for some software to get it to work, but I am not dishing out money.  Another proposed solution is to download `x360ce.ini` and put it in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\DuckTales Remastered\executable`, but I tried this and it does not work.

There has to be a way to get this to work.  Anyone know?

Comment: Have you tried to use the [x360ce Xbox 360 controller emulator](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/) and is the .ini file set up for your controller, or is it just a random .ini?

Comment: I don't know.  I looked into it and it's way too complicated.  I just want to get this Gamepad to work with DuckTales just like it works with everything else with as little reading as possible.  Edit:  Plus, I hear that this emulator creates controller lag (ie, slight delay between button press and actual action ingame).

Comment: Well, if the game only supports Xbox360 controllers and your logitech isn't supported, you either have to jump through some hoops or get yourself a Xbox360 controller (or one that is recognised by games as such). Regarding Controller lag - I wouldn't worry about that yet. Priority should be to get your controller working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a general solution like [Joy2Key (free)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joy2key/) or [XPadder ($10)](http://xpadder.com). I'm using them even for games with no joystick support at all and they work pretty well.

You can get Joy2Key [binaries here](http://www.electracode.com/4/joy2key/JoyToKey%20English%20Version.htm).

Comment: Good idea - needs a bit time setting-up, but should be easier than x360ce.

Comment: Downloaded Joy2Key from SourceForce, but the archive contains no EXE.  It's like it's the source code files.  Where is the installation EXE?  No idea how to use this.  Also, as stated in my question, I am not paying money, so XPadder is out.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin I've updated with link to binaries.

Comment: Sweet!  I am using it and it's working.  It's too bad that you have to use such a hack, especially with a new game, but it's all good in the end.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

[**x360ce**](https://github.com/x360ce/x360ce) works well with my china shop special controller. Copy the .exe file into Executable folder and create xinput files, then start the game from the x360ce application ("Game Settings" tab).